# Laravel merging configs in Laravel packages

Tags: php, laravel, package, config

I'm writing a package on laravel that it require some packages to install.

I want to overwrite own package configuration file with the applications's published copy, and use the mergeConfigFrom method within my package service provider's register method. but it dosent work as i expect

> app/config/publishedConfig.php

```
return [
  'dashboard_url' => 'home',
  'logout_url' => 'logout',
  'login_url' => 'login'
];
```

And

> package/vendor/path/to/config/config.php

```
return [
   'dashboard_url' => 'dashboard/login',
   'logout_url' => 'dashboard/logout',
   'login_url' => 'mongodb-login'
]
```

Then in register method on my package service provider i use mergeConfigFrom like below to overwrite publishedConfig on run time:

```
public function register(){

    $this->mergeConfigFrom(
         __DIR__.'/config/adminlte-logo.php','publishedConfig'
    );
}
```

After that I use `dd(config('publishedConfig'))` helper to get result of merge But the result not changed.

expected result is :

```
   'dashboard_url' => 'dashboard/login',
   'logout_url' => 'dashboard/logout',
   'login_url' => 'mongodb-login'
```

I will appreciate anyone who solve my issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected result? Are you sure `mergeConfigFrom()` _overwrites_ existing values, or does it just add new values that don't exist yet?

Comment: I think you are right , It just add new values, expected result is what array_merge function do. remove the old repetitive key values and return new one.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have overwrite it in `--force` tag way.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=config --force
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Laravel Documents](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/packages#default-package-configuration),

> You may also merge your own package configuration file with the
> application's published copy. This will allow your users to define
> only the options they actually want to override in the published copy
> of the configuration file.

Imagine you have a config file in your application's config files path named **myConfig.php**:

```
// myConfig.php
<?php

return [
    'key' => 'my-key',
];
```

On the other hand, you have a config file in your package named **packageConfig.php**:

```
// packageConfig.php
<?php

return [
    'key' => 'package-key',
    'foo' => 'bar',
];
```

**Register** method on my package service provider must be like the below:

```
public function register(){
   $this->mergeConfigFrom(
      __DIR__.'/../config/packageConfig.php', 'myConfig'
   );
}
```

It means that the values of the keys in the **packageConfig.php** file will be overwritten by the values of the keys in the **myConfig.php** in run time.

Expected result for **dd(config('packageConfig'))** is:

```
'key' => 'my-key',
'foo' => 'bar',
```

There is a very good explanation [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-does-mergeconfigfrom-work) by [@MarkRedeman](https://laracasts.com/@MarkRedeman).